# SQL Group by Totals issue

Tags: sql, date, grouping

I am having some real trouble with this, below is the code, I am try to get counts from two different tables then group them by date.

```
declare @fromdate as date
declare @todate as date
set @fromdate = CONVERT(date,GETDATE()-3,101)
set @todate = CONVERT(date,GETDATE(),101)

USE database
SELECT
    CONVERT(date,created_date,101) as OrdDate,
    col1=   (SELECT COUNT(distinct cust_id) 
        FROM table1 
        WHERE created_date BETWEEN @fromdate and @todate),
    col2=   (SELECT COUNT(distinct cust_id) 
        FROM table1 
        WHERE [status] LIKE 'P%' and created_date BETWEEN @fromdate and @todate),
    col3=   (SELECT COUNT(distinct cust_id) 
        FROM table2 
        WHERE created_date BETWEEN @fromdate and @todate),
    col4=   (SELECT COUNT(distinct cust_id) 
        FROM table2 
        WHERE created_date between @fromdate and @todate and result_error like 'FAIL%')

FROM table1
WHERE created_date BETWEEN @fromdate and @todate

GROUP BY CONVERT(date,created_date,101)
ORDER BY CONVERT(date,created_date,101)
```

It is counting all of the days together, I have tried adding Group by to each expression, no go. Any suggestions?

```
OrdDate     col1    col2    col3    col4
2011-12-19  5000    4000    3000    2000
2011-12-20  5000    4000    3000    2000
2011-12-21  5000    4000    3000    2000
```

What I want is something like this

```
OrdDate     col1    col2    col3    col4
2011-12-19  1500    1500    500     750
2011-12-20  2500    750     1000    1000
2011-12-21  1000    1750    1500    250
```

Comment: if you remove the group by what is the result?

Comment: What if you don't have 2011-12-20 in one table? Generally, you don't do this kind of disjoint aggregate because of this unless you want one row

Comment: There are actually three tables in this query - table1, customer_order and table2.

Comment: aF - results are similar to results above except I am now getting them for all occurances of [created_date]

Comment: Mark - sorry customer_order should read table1.

Comment: Question updated accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to generate a list of dates first, then JOIN back to that for each count.

This will remove issues with different row counts for each aggregate

```
SELECT
    base.TheDate AS OrdDare,
    ISNULL(T1.C1, 0) AS col1, 
    ISNULL(T2.C2, 0) AS col2, 
    ISNULL(T3.C3, 0) AS col3, 
    ISNULL(T4.C4, 0) AS col4
FROM
    ( -- UNION will also DISTINCT
     SELECT CONVERT(date,created_date,101) AS TheDate FROM table1
     WHERE created_date BETWEEN @fromdate and @todate
     UNION
     SELECT CONVERT(date,created_date,101) FROM table2
     WHERE created_date BETWEEN @fromdate and @todate
    ) base
    LEFT JOIN
    (
     SELECT CONVERT(date,created_date,101) AS TheDate, COUNT(distinct cust_id) AS C1
        FROM table1 
        WHERE created_date BETWEEN @fromdate and @todate
        GROUP BY CONVERT(date,created_date,101)
    ) T1 ON base.TheDate = T1.TheDate 
    LEFT JOIN
    (
      SELECT CONVERT(date,created_date,101) AS TheDate, COUNT(distinct cust_id) AS C2
        FROM table1 
        WHERE WHERE [status] LIKE 'P%' and created_date BETWEEN @fromdate and @todate
        GROUP BY CONVERT(date,created_date,101)
    ) T2 ON base.TheDate = T2.TheDate 
    LEFT JOIN
    (
     SELECT CONVERT(date,created_date,101) AS TheDate, COUNT(distinct cust_id) AS C3
        FROM table2
        WHERE created_date BETWEEN @fromdate and @todate
        GROUP BY CONVERT(date,created_date,101)
    ) T3 ON base.TheDate = T3.TheDate 
    LEFT JOIN
    (
     SELECT CONVERT(date,created_date,101) AS TheDate, COUNT(distinct cust_id) AS C4
        FROM table2
        WHERE created_date BETWEEN @fromdate and @todate and result_error like 'FAIL%'
        GROUP BY CONVERT(date,created_date,101)
    ) T4 ON base.TheDate = T4.TheDate 
ORDER BY
     base.TheDate;
```

Comment: gbn - the columns don't have headers and all dates are being presented, any ideas on how to restrict the results to just the defined range?

Comment: Add a WHERE to the base derived table. Add column aliases. Done

Answer (score 0):

You need to do that group by in each aggregate query you need.

Currently, you are only group by the table1, and you want, in each subquery, also group by date. And you can remove that group by in the main query I believe...

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select CONVERT(date,created_date,101) OrdDate,
       count(distinct table1_cust)    col1,
       count(distinct table1_cust_p)  col2,
       count(distinct table2_cust)    col3,
       count(distinct table2_fail)    col4
from
(select distinct 
       created_date,
       cust_id       table1_cust,
       case when [status] LIKE 'P%' then cust_id end
                     table1_cust_p,
       NULL          table2_cust,
       NULL          table2_fail
 FROM table1 
 WHERE created_date BETWEEN @fromdate and @todate
 UNION ALL
 select distinct 
       created_date,
       NULL          table1_cust,
       NULL          cust_order,
       cust_id       table2_cust,
       case when result_error like 'FAIL%' then cust_id end
                     table2_fail
 FROM table2 
 WHERE created_date BETWEEN @fromdate and @todate) v
group by created_date
```

EDIT: Updated after clarification of question.